# How to achieve the perfect material for an aircraft glass canopy

Tags: materials, node-editor, shader-nodes

Well, in my previous question I asked the same thing , i got some **good results** but it *looks unrealistic* till the core here is one.

[image]

My **node setup** for the glass was like this

[image]

I wanted to achieve this kind of quality.  For the body I can easily do this **but the glass is so tough**.

[image]

Last time a guy called **Jachym Michal** helped me a lot by sharing me the appropriate term , but I **would like to see someone try it themselves and achieve the glass effect as seen in the above pic**.

Comment: There are a few problems with your node tree here. It's not usually a good idea to mix Glass with Transparent unless you know exactly what you are doing. Also, I see that some Diffuse has been added at grazing angles with the Fresnel node; this is usually done to make an object look dusty, but I doubt that you want that for an aircraft in flight.

Comment: Agree with the above.. and exactly the 'right' glass will look _very_ different under different lighting conditions.. This is a cool bright skyscape, with frosty aerial perspective. If you cant generate that at this early stage, could you find a reference image in lighting that you can simulate easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well let me say you that almost every jet has something called iridescence effect and you have tried hard to fake it but its ot a big deal to do  it you need to know that the effect of iridescence is created only in the border of the glass take for example this[image]  and also the effect is minute in some angles but more visible in some , for the effect you need to use noise and hue saturation nodes. here is the setup[image]and here is the result [3][image]
[image]note if you want more colorful effect then reduce the factor of fresnel .also make sure to apply solidify modifiers to your glass . greetings !!!

Comment: great that works very well .